# How to highlight different parts of text with multiple colors in HTML

Tags: html, css, highlight

Let's say we have a piece of text and we want to highlight different parts of the text with different colors like the following:

[image]

Highlight can include potential overlaps between text spans as shown in the example above. I am just wondering what kind of technology I need to use/utilize to achieve this? Should I be playing around CSS and HTML to see how I can define a class for `span` or `mark` tags in my HTML? Or is there anything free and ready to go so that I can just generate my text with proper tags and put it in my HTML to generate colored text?

My templates are in `HTML5`.

Comment: You can't unless you overlap elements using positioning.

Comment: @Paulie_D what if we disregard the overlaps and just want to highlight the text spans with different colors? Also would be great if you give me an example of what you mean by overlapping elements using positioning.

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue that may seem to be simple but turns out to be non-trivial. You can't try to partially overlap elements as they'll cascade with one fully contained in the other. The following doesn't highlight the start of the sentence with purple, the middle with both purple and green, and the end with green. Instead, it highlights the entire sentence with purple and the middle section with green.

`<span class="purple">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, <span class="green">sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut</span> labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span>`

While positioning could be used to put highlights of the proper size in positions such that they overlap, it is an approach that is difficult to make responsive.

Instead, I have implemented this appearance by fully enclosing another highlight tag where two highlights overlap, then starting another highlight immediately after the previous highlight.

Because your desired appearance has rounded corners that should only appear at the very start and very end of a highlight, I use a `start` and `end` class to indicate where an enclosed overlapping highlight starts and ends.

```css
.highlight {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 36px;
}
.highlight span {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 3px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.highlight span span {
    margin: 0 -3px;
}
.highlight .start {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-right: none;
}
.highlight .end {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-left: none;
}
.highlight .purple {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.15);
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}
.highlight .green {
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.15);
    border-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}
.highlight .orange {
    background-color: rgba(255, 150, 0, 0.15);
    border-color: rgba(255, 150, 0, 0.5);
}
.highlight .red {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}   
.highlight .yellow {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.15);
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5);
}
.highlight .blue {
    background-color: rgba(0, 150, 255, 0.15);
    border-color: rgba(0, 150, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="highlight">
    <span class="purple">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, <span class="green start">sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut</span></span><span class="green end"> labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud <span class="orange">exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse <span class="red">cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <span class="yellow start">Excepteur sint</span></span><span class="yellow end"> occaecat cupidatat non proident, <span class="blue start">sunt in culpa qui officia</span></span><span class="blue end"> deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
</div>
```